# Is the CHAMP missile capable of doing what they say it does?

Tags: electromagnetism, microwaves

[CHAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electronics_High_Power_Microwave_Advanced_Missile_Project), A new counter-electronics directed energy USAF weapon was created by Boeing Phantom Works
with the intention to damage and / or destroy electronic target equipment without causing structural damage,
is set to be launched and operated from a cruise missile platform according to the latest info out
and would be equipped with a multi-shot, multi-target, high-power microwave electromagnetic gun
firing microwave projectiles, causing sudden surges in electricity and disabling / destroying all electric equipment;
this would be a non-kinetic alternative to traditional explosive weapons that use the energy of motion to defeat a target,
and could shoot as much as 100 times in a single sortie before the missile self-destructs, these are their own words.

Now I am a bit doubtful of this, since this weapon sounds too good to be true from a Physics perspective.
Since decades there has been ECM and ECCM out there in jamming forms and most advanced weapon systems,
no matter if on land, air or sea, are being build with enough hardware to protect systems from these kind of attacks.

So my question to the Physicists out there is: could actually such a weapon **theoretically** do what the marketting people
of BPW are claiming with MW technology, bypassing common ECM hardware protections and not causing structural damage
when we know that an EMP can cause fires anywhere as it flows through metal, for example?

Comment: Reported in [2009](http://www.popularmechanics.com/military/a12315/4319720/), tested in [2012](http://www.boeing.com/features/2012/10/bds-champ-10-22-12.page) against typical commercial PCs (actually rather elderly ones with CRT displays) in a typical office building - not against EMP-hardened targets.

Comment: Short of testing it out or actually having the blueprints and specs, I don't think your question can be answered.

Comment: This isn't a question about physics. At best it's an engineering question.

Comment: @John not a question about physics? So the effects of ELECTROMAGNETISM and MICROWAVES is on the field of Engineering? I am not asking is the missile can fly here; I'm asking if a device shooting microwave particle ammunition can do what they say it does, even theoretically. Period. And that is in the realm and portfolio of Physics, not Engineering

Comment: @Horus as per RedGrittyBrick comment, they tested agains old CRT PCs, there is a video out there. So they did function on that very old-fashioned unprotected equipment, that is already tested. I wanted to know from physics academics people here if this is theoretically possible to overcome currently known EMP-hardened targets (thx RGB for the better term) using mere Microwave technology as they say. So they have a weapon that can take out 286 PCs... not the most effective weapon out there if that's all they can target

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but as a military weapon about as useful as a wackadoodle and possibly an automatic warcrime charge, since such systems would overwhelmingly damage non-military infrastructure. Just to give you an idea: a pair of 5 cent 1N4148 diodes can withstand 10us multi-A RF pulses for virtually ever. To make these pulses into a $50\Omega$ system in the first place, you need a direct coax connection into a $$5k RF power amplifier. If you take that coax out and go with an antenna, now you need MW pulses.

Comment: @CuriousOne So what you are saying with "overwhelmingly damage non-military infrastructure" is that you do not believe at all that the projectiles / burst effect can be "smart" guided and is basically a centered burst / carpet attack, damaging everything regardless?

Comment: What I am saying is that commercial equipment manufacturers are saving ten cents of effective EMP-protection wherever they can and they integrate all functions of an electronic system into one chip, where possible. That leaves no room for energy reflecting and absorbing parts, which make these electronic systems susceptible. If you design the same functionality with EMP in mind, it will be larger, bulkier (a little more expensive) and completely insensitive. In some cases you have to design it that way even without EMP threats for thermal and ruggedness reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an EMP device, not an ECM device:  in particular, it's not trying to disrupt communication by emitting suitable EM noise of the right kind which is what ECM does, it's trying to emit a big enough pulse of brute-force-and-ignorance energy to cause electronics to physically fail by inducing large enough voltages across various bad places in electronic systems.  Such devices can work theoretically.  I believe this answers your question.

Considerations of the energy density of conventional power sources and the inverse square law tell you that it's not going to be setting things on fire very far away from it, so that is not a problem.

---

Whether it can work against systems hardened against EMP is another question, and not really one in the realm of physics. Since nuclear weapons are extremely good sources of EMP, anything designed in the later part of the cold war or afterwards by the major powers, and intended to be used in that war will presumably be hardened against EMP.

Whether it is *intended* to work against hardened systems is another question.  The fashionable antagonists for the sort of countries which might buy such a device nowadays tend not to use enormously advanced technology: if it can disrupt a phone embedded in something nasty perhaps that is enough.

Comment: So a less-than-state-of-art-empowered-enemy targetting weapon. makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Weapons like this have existed for decades. They are normally either explosive [flux compression generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator) or [Vircator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vircator) based

Comment: Food for thought and further research, thank you Dirk, I will inquire further into this.